# how do you list git commits with their tags interleaved in the output?

Tags: git, diff, tagging

I have some code that gets lots of commits and is tagged often too.

I would like to see what commits are for each tag and I then I will do a git diff between the tags to see the actual code changes.

**how do you list git commits with their tags interleaved in the output?**

---

i was thinking something like this output would allow me to see what commits were for each tag:

```
${short_commit_hash} ${commit_date} ${first_line_of_text_from_commit_message}
${short_commit_hash} ${commit_date} ${first_line_of_text_from_commit_message}
${short_commit_hash} ${commit_date} ${first_line_of_text_from_commit_message}
${tag_name} ${tag_date}
${short_commit_hash} ${commit_date} ${first_line_of_text_from_commit_message}
${short_commit_hash} ${commit_date} ${first_line_of_text_from_commit_message}
${short_commit_hash} ${commit_date} ${first_line_of_text_from_commit_message}
${tag_name} ${tag_date}
```

however this output is not a strict requirement. this is just one idea i came up with that would help me see what commits were from each tag.

there may be easy git commands that already do most of what I am asking and those commands might be really easy/straight-forward.

Comment: `git log --format=format:'%h %ci %s%n%D'` gets you 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want the tags interleaved.  You want a newline in the log format before the tag.  With that in mind, just do:

```
git log --format=format:'%h %ci %s%+D'
```

From the `git-log` documentation: If you add a + (plus sign) after % of a placeholder, a line-feed is inserted immediately before the expansion if and only if the placeholder expands to a non-empty string.